# Resources for multivariate normal distribution

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution

Is there any particular book/online notes that I can use to better understand the multivariate normal distribution? I could also do with a bunch of questions and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There is the **book**
**Tong, Y. L. (1990). The multivariate normal distribution.(Springer)**

I also consider useful the **paper**

**[Hamedani, G. G. (1992). Bivariate and multivariate normal characterizations: a brief survey. Communications in Statistics-Theory and Methods, 21(9), 2665-2688.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/03610929208830936)**